# What restrictions are placed on the values of each case of switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

For this question i saw a answer like **During compilation, the values of each case of a switch statement must evaluate to a value that can be promoted to an int value** but i didn't understood why because we are also using byte, short, int, char but this statement only saying about int so please explain me and give me an example for this

Comment: Where did you find the question and the restriction? What version of Java is the question talking about?

Comment: It may be referring to in case if you try to use wrapper classes. Because of auto boxing, an Integer object can be null in run-time so if you try to use the Integer object as parameter it will fail.

Comment: @Phani the question mentions restrictions, not possible side effects, like NPE etc. Restrictions come for the JLS.

Comment: Its not side effects.. Prior to 1.7 Java ..Switch block only accepts byte, short, char, and int as parameters..its a restriction.. because you can't use boolean for switch as it has only true/false. From 1.7 Java introduced String which technically means any object which has toString overridden can be used for Switch block..and only reason is its more readable.

Comment: Wrapper classes with value as null can't be promoted to int value.

Comment: @Phani "Wrapper classes with value as null can't be promoted to int value." that is a side effect only visible during runtime and not a compile time restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumeration types were introduced in Java 5, and the `switch` statement was enhanced at the same time to allow switching on an `enum` value.

That invalidates the quoted statement:

> "[d]uring compilation, the values of each case of a switch statement must evaluate to a value that can be promoted to an int value"

... unless it refers to Java 1.4.x or earlier.

What it is saying is that case values must be `byte`, `short`, `char` or `int`.  (These are the only types whose values can be 
promoted to `int` ... prior to Java 5.  Unboxing of wrapper types was introduced in Java 5 as well.)

Of course, that ceased to be true in Java 5.  In Java 5 and later, the constants can be `enum` values, and in Java 7 and later they can also be `String` values (depending on the type of the selector expression).

The other think to note is that you should be reading the relevant version of the JLS for definitive information ... not relying on some StackOverflow question.  In this case, the JLS expresses the restriction more simply and more directly.

Reference:

- [JSR 00201 - Extending the JavaTM Programming Language with Enumerations, Autoboxing, Enhanced for loops and Static Import](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr201/index2.html)

(I couldn't find a public copy of the Java 5 JLS to link to ...)

Answer (score -1):

Java Language Specification is always the best place to check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/statements.html#14.11

Edit: Pasted the link to JLS SE6. Still, JLS **is** the best place to check.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about a version of JDK prior to JDK 1.7?